# Retrieving returned POST data in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been trying to call a server-side POST function to authenticate a user in a web-application. Both my ExpressJS and my ReactJS environments are configured and running correctly, one on port 3000 and one on 3001.

I'm able to call the functions and execute the server-side Express code, however when I try to access the returned value in React, the value appears to be undefined. Would love some help!

React Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class tem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    var testVar = {
      key: "0000000000",
      status: false
    };
    this.state = {
      users: [],
      username: "",
      password: "",
      submitted: "yes",
      responseData: testVar
    };
    this.handleNameChange = this.handleNameChange.bind(this);
    this.handlePassChange = this.handlePassChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.getResponse = this.getResponse.bind(this);
  }

  handleNameChange(e) {
    this.setState({ username: e.target.value });
  }
  handlePassChange(e) {
    this.setState({ password: e.target.value });
  }

  getResponse(urlPath, user, pass) {
    let setResp = this;
    fetch(urlPath, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password
      })
    })
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        setResp.setState({ responseData: response });
      });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ submitted: "YES" });
    this.setState({
      responseData: this.getResponse(
        "/login",
        this.state.username,
        this.state.password
      )
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>login </h1>
        Enter your username
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search..."
            value={this.props.filterText}
            onChange={this.handleNameChange}
          />
          Enter your password
          <input
            type="password"
            placeholder="enter password"
            value={this.props.filterText}
            onChange={this.handlePassChange}
          />
          <button type="submit">Start</button>
        </form>
        {this.state.responseData.key}
        {this.state.submitted}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm later trying to access reponseData.key, and I get the following error:

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRZzf.png)

My outputted JSON is:

```
{
    "key": "408f51qk54",
    "status": true
}
```

I tried it through Postman and it's working fine. I can't figure out what the error is!

Comment: does `responseData` have a value in your state initially? If it's initially undefined, then you'll get that error. The `fetch` is asynchronous so the component will render first, before the `fetch` response comes back

Comment: @Jayce444 yes it does! I've filled it with dummy JSON data.

Comment: @RajuThonde Could you include the rest of your component in your question?

Comment: @Tholle Done, updated the source code.

Comment: @RajuThonde You should just call `this.getResponse` in your `handleSubmit` method, not call `setState` with it. Since you are not returning anything from `this.getResponse`, that will make `responseData` be `undefined`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`response.json()` returns a promise, so make sure you return that in the promise chain before you use the response in `setState`.

```
let setResp = this;
fetch(urlPath, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    username: this.state.username,
    password: this.state.password
  })
})
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    setResp.setState({ responseData: response });
  });
```

You should not call `setState` with the result from `this.getResponse` either, since you are not returning anything from `this.getResponse` and it is asynchronous. That will make your `responseData` be `undefined.`

Just call `this.getResponse` instead:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  this.setState({ submitted: "YES" });
  this.getResponse(
    "/login",
    this.state.username,
    this.state.password
  );
}
```

Comment: @RajuThonde That's frustrating. I updated the answer with a second thing to keep in mind.

Comment: Use a callback function on the response so you make sure the promise is filled.

Answer (score 1):

For example you're returning data from .post like that:

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
// server side code
    res.json(/*returning data*/);
});
```

So in React code you retrieve it like that:

```
functionThatMakePostRequest = (args) => {
const data = {
    id: 555,
    name: "name",
};

fetch('/', {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
})
.then(res => res.json()) //returns array of data
.then(res => this.setState({ res })); //assign state to array res
};
```

Comment: is this something working to catch data from a WooCommerce authentication endpoint ? WooCommerce provide an authentication endpoint to generate authentication key. when reaching this address (more a web address you open in a browser), WooCommerce display a pop-up to let you accept or not. when you accept, the submit a PUT to the callback provided during the first call. but it seems a separate PUT